# SQL Server: Creating transposed table and joining with existing table

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, create-table, join

I have a set of data from table [MSPWIP].[MSPWIP].[Event] that looks like this:

```
| Createdby | StationName | SerialNumber |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   Jay     |    L1.A1    | 22191321572  |
|   Allan   |    L1.A2    | 22191321572  |
|   Nathan  |    L2.A1    | 22191321579  |
|   Jane    |    L2.A2    | 22191321579  |
```

And I have other sets of data that I have already joined in another query which is not relevant to the problem

I want to create a table separating the operator (denoted by createdby) by stations where L1.A1 means Line 1 Station 1 for example. For me at the moment, Line is not relevant

My ideal data after I restructure it should look like this

```
| SerialNumber | Operator1 | Operator2 |
----------------------------------------
| 22191321572  |    Jay    |   Allan   |
| 22191321579  |   Nathan  |   Jane    |
```

I tried using this code to Join both tables:

Query#1

```
Declare @Operator1 Table(
SerialNumber Varchar(255),
Operator1 Varchar(255)
)

Insert Into @Operator1 (Serialnumber, Operator1)
Select 
SerialNumber,
Createdby as Operator1
From [MSPWIP].[MSPWIP].[Event]
where StationName like '%01'

Declare @Operator2 Table(
SerialNumber Varchar(255),
Operator2 Varchar(255)
)

Insert Into @Operator2 (Serialnumber, Operator2)
Select 
SerialNumber,
CreatedBy as Operator2
From [MSPWIP].[MSPWIP].[Event]
where StationName like '%02'

select 
a.SerialNumber,
CreatedBy,
b.Operator2

From @Operator1 a
join @Operator2 b
On a.SerialNumber = b.SerialNumber

Where a.SerialNumber In ('22191321572', '22191321574')
```

Then I would like to join it with that other query using the code below:

Query#2

```
join @Operator1 i
on a.SerialNumber = i.SerialNumber
join @Operator2 j
on a.SerialNumber = j.SerialNumber
```

- Note that a is a different table.

However with Query#1 it only managed to show the headings and not the data, and this also caused Query#2 to also display heading and nothing else.

Just wondering if there was something wrong with Query#1 where the data failed to be inserted into the columns?

============================================

## Update:

Using the answer below (with Modifications) I came up with a code like this

Query#3

```
SELECT Distinct*
FROM (
    SELECT distinct
        SerialNumber,
        Case When t.StationName like '%A1' then CreatedBy End Operator1,
        Case When t.StationName like '%A2' then CreatedBy End Operator2
    --,   Max(CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(t.StationName, 1) AS Varchar(255)) = 1 THEN t.CreatedBy END) Operator1 
    --,   Max(CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(t.StationName, 1) AS Varchar(255)) = 2 THEN t.CreatedBy END) Operator2 
    FROM [MSPWIP].[MSPWIP].[Event] t
    where t.CreatedDate > '2019-05-30'
    Group BY SerialNumber, StationName, Createdby
) d
```

However my results now became staggered like so:

```
| SerialNumber | Operator1 | Operator2 |
----------------------------------------
| 22191321572  |    Jay    |   NULL    |
| 22191321572  |    NULL   |   Allan   |
| 22191321579  |   Nathan  |   NULL    |
| 22191321579  |    NULL   |   Jane    |
```

Did i do something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your time by doing it in one run like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SerialNumber
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(t.StationName, 2) = '01' THEN t.Operator END) Operator1 
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(t.StationName, 2) = '02' THEN t.Operator END) Operator2 
    FROM [MSPWIP].[MSPWIP].[Event] t
    GROUP BY SerialNumber
) d
```

then you just join it with the required tables.

P.S : If your station part in the `StationName` is not always a number, then you can use `SUBSTRING(t.StationName, CHARINDEX('.', t.StationName) + 1, LEN(t.StationName))` instead of `RIGHT(t.StationName, 2)`  to get the station part (which is after the dot).

Comment: Thank you very much, The code sort of works, however i faced the issue where i get a conversion failure when converting Varchar of station name into int. I should clarify that my data in "Station name" can contain letters in the last 2 digits and the data above is an arbitrary example. Sorry about that. 
I noticed that the Max and Cast syntax returns int, is there anything that returns Varchar?

Comment: @EugeneKwokKitHo check the edit, this should solve it, however, read the P.S if your station name can be more than 2 characters, use the `SUBSTRING` method instead.

Comment: I managed to use case when StationName is Like X instead and got the operators to show. Thank you! however my results seem to be staggered (Operator 1 and 2 shows in different rows and the other operator shows Null.) I have updated my problem statement.

Comment: Hi, it works perfectly with your P.S Now, thank you!

Comment: @EugeneKwokKitHo glad to help, just mark it answered, to help other researchers.